# Copy files from parent folder with grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: grunt-contrib-copy

I am trying to copy files over from a parent folder using grunt-contrib-copy. My folder structure is:

```
-libs
  -html5shiv
  -respond
  -jquery
-apps
  -exampleApp1
    -GruntFile.js
    -build
  -exampleApp2
    -GruntFile.js
    -build
```

I am trying to copy all the JavaScript files from the libs folder over to the apps/exampleApp1/build when I run the GruntFile.js in exampleApp1. I have the following setup in the GruntFile.js:

```
build_dir: 'build';

lib_files: {
  js: [
    '../../libs/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js',
    '../../libs/respond/dest/respond.min.js',
    '../../libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
  ]
};

copy: {
  build_libjs: {
    files: [
      {
        src: [ '<%= lib_files.js %>' ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
        cwd: '.',
        expand: true            
      }
    ]
  },
```

},

At the moment it copies all the files over to apps/libs because of the '../../' each file has in the lib_files.js array. How can I make sure that the files end up in the build folder like so?:

```
-apps
  -exampleApp1
    -GruntFile.js
    -build
      -libs
        -html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js
        -libs/respond/dest/respond.min.js
        -jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite simple actually. There is a rename function which can be used in combination with grunt-contrib-copy.

"You just need to attach one parameter to my configuration, which overrides the standard rename function of the Grunt file utilities.".

from:

http://fettblog.eu/blog/2014/05/27/undocumented-features-rename/

I combined this with a simple regular expression and problem solved:

```
  build_libjs: {
    files: [
      {
        src: [ '<%= lib_files.js %>' ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
        cwd: '.',
        expand: true,
        rename: function(dest, src) {
          //Replace '../../' with an empty string
          return dest + ( src.replace(/^..\/..\// ,"") );
        }           
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **cwd** property to change the source directory

```
lib_files: {


js: [
    'html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js',
    'respond/dest/respond.min.js',
    'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
  ]
};

copy: {
  build_libjs: {
    files: [
      {
        src: [ '<%= lib_files.js %>' ],
        dest: '<%= build_dir %>/',
        cwd: '../libs',
        expand: true            
      }
    ]
  },
```